# MS Access Stops Working Only When Changing a Specific Method

Tags: vba, ms-access, crash

Access crashes whenever I try to edit a specific method in my VBA.  The method is an event raised by a "WithEvents" member object of the form.  I have tried editing other methods in the application and everything works like normal.  I cannot highlight, delete, add a new line, or type a key anywhere that is part of this method. I can do all of this in other methods in the form's module.  It seems to be an issue with Access and not any of my code?

I have tried a restart.  I have tried deleting the method, but it just crashes again.  I have tried editing the method in both the "original" file and the "backup" file Access creates when it crashes, but both fail.

This is the problem method:

```
Private Sub approvalDialog_FormClosed(ByVal dialogForm as clsDialogManager,  Cancel as Boolean)
    Set MOCForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have private subs above and below the method that work fine.

EDIT:
I should add that this is on my work computer, so I do not have admin rights to do any repairs on apps or re-downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

1. I exported the module
2. Used ctrl+A and delete to clear the module in VBEditor
3. Opened the exported module in Notepad and copied all of the text
4. Pasted the copied code back into the module in the VBEditor
5. Deleted the all of the "non-code" (e.g. Attributes)

I don't know what the problem was, but it seems to be fixed.